# Android Orientation change results in app crashing

Tags: java, android

This has only happened once but I'm a bit concerned with it. I was testing the app changing the orientation and the application crashed. Never happened before so just want to see if anyone else has had this issue and what I could do to fix it. Please see the log below:

```
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity      ComponentInfo{com./.hearing.InstructionsActivity}:     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3740)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1262)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:133)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at   com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at .InstructionsActivity.onCreate(InstructionsActivity.java:40)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     ... 12 more
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     ... 26 more
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:800)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2105)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>  (ImageView.java:127)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:117)
05-15 12:13:07.304: E/AndroidRuntime(2596):     ... 29 more
```

So to me it looks like it had a issue with inflating the layout. I don't see how because I'd changed the orientation about 4 times before it crashed.

A bit further down there is a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` error so I assume this has caused the `android.view.InflateException`.

Any help of this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**Edit:**

Here is the activity it crashed on:

```
public class InstructionsActivity extends MenuActivity {
private ScrollView mScrollButton;
private WebView topContent;
private WebView bottomContent;
private boolean mMoreInfoTop = false;
private int mYdelta = 0;
private int mBottomOffset = 0;
private ActivityHelper activityHelper;
private boolean isPhone;
private String topHtml;
private String bottomHtml;
private String flag;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.instructions);

    activityHelper = new ActivityHelper(this);
    activityHelper.getScreenTag(R.id.instructions);
    activityHelper.getDrawableFolder();
    activityHelper.setTitleTextSize(R.string.Hearing_Test, true);
    isPhone = activityHelper.isPhone();

    if(isPhone){
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    mScrollButton = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
    flag = String.valueOf(getIntent().getStringExtra("Flag"));

    if (flag.equalsIgnoreCase("firstInstructions")) {
        topHtml = this.getString(R.string.top_content);

        Button startTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test);
        startTest.setText(R.string.start_test);
    }else if(flag.equalsIgnoreCase("secondInstructions")){
        topHtml = this.getString(R.string.switch_file);

        Button startTest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test);
        startTest.setText(R.string.continue_test);
    }

    bottomHtml = this.getString(R.string.bottom_content);
    topContent = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.top_content);
    topContent.setBackgroundColor(0);
    bottomContent = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_content);
    bottomContent.setBackgroundColor(0);
    bottomContent.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);

    topContent.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/" + topHtml);
    bottomContent.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/" + bottomHtml);

    getMargins();

    setResult(RESULT_OK);
}

public void getMargins() {

    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = topContent.getViewTreeObserver();

    viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            int topHeight = topContent.getMeasuredHeight();
            int bottomHeight = bottomContent.getMeasuredHeight();

            if (isPhone) {
                if (topHeight != 0) {
                    Log.d("Web View Height", "Continue Height: "
                            + topHeight);
                    if (mScrollButton != null) {
                        RelativeLayout instructions = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.more_info);
                        instructions.post(mAddMargin);
                        topContent.getViewTreeObserver()
                                .removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    }
                    topContent.getViewTreeObserver()
                            .removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                }
            } else if (!isPhone) {
                if (topHeight != 0 && bottomHeight != 0) {
                    Log.d("Web View Height", "top Height: " + topHeight
                            + "bottom height:" + bottomHeight);
                    RelativeLayout instructions = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.more_info);
                    instructions.post(mAddMargin);
                    topContent.getViewTreeObserver()
                            .removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}

Runnable mAddMargin = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            int marginHeight;

            if (isPhone) {
                marginHeight = activityHelper.getMarginHeight(R.id.more_info, R.id.bottom_content);
                RelativeLayout buttonHolder = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.instructionsLayout);
                mBottomOffset = buttonHolder.getBottom();
                mScrollButton = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
                mYdelta = mScrollButton.getScrollY();
                activityHelper.setMarginHeight(marginHeight, R.id.instructionsLayout);
            } else if (!isPhone) {
 //                 int sideMargin = activityHelper.getWebViewMargin(R.id.bottom_content);
//                  if(sideMargin != 0){
//                      activityHelper.setWebViewMargin(sideMargin, R.id.top_content);
//                      activityHelper.setWebViewMargin(sideMargin, R.id.bottom_content);
//                  }
                marginHeight = activityHelper.getMarginHeight(R.id.more_info, R.id.bottom_content);
                activityHelper.setMarginHeight(marginHeight, R.id.more_info);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Scroll View", "Couldn't run mAddMargin:", e);
        }
    }
};

public void onClickHandler(View aView) {

    if (flag.equalsIgnoreCase("firstInstructions")) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, HearingTestActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if(flag.equalsIgnoreCase("secondInstructions")){
        finish();
    }
}

public void infoView(View aView) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onMoreInstructions(View aView) {
    // Scroll the start button to the top of the screen.
    mScrollButton.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mMoreInfoTop) {
                mMoreInfoTop = false;
                mScrollButton.scrollTo(0, mYdelta);
            } else {
                mMoreInfoTop = true;
                mScrollButton.scrollTo(0, mBottomOffset);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Do you need any other code from me?

**New code:**

This is my updated code:

```
public void getMargins() {

    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = topContent.getViewTreeObserver();

    x = new OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            int topHeight = topContent.getMeasuredHeight();
            int bottomHeight = bottomContent.getMeasuredHeight();

            if (isPhone) {
                if (topHeight != 0) {
                    Log.d("Web View Height", "Continue Height: "
                            + topHeight);
                    if (mScrollButton != null) {
                        RelativeLayout instructions = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.more_info);
                        instructions.post(mAddMargin);
                        topContent.getViewTreeObserver()
                                .removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                    }
                    topContent.getViewTreeObserver()
                            .removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                }
            } else if (!isPhone) {
                if (topHeight != 0 && bottomHeight != 0) {
                    Log.d("Web View Height", "top Height: " + topHeight
                            + "bottom height:" + bottomHeight);
                    RelativeLayout instructions = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.more_info);
                    instructions.post(mAddMargin);
                    topContent.getViewTreeObserver()
                            .removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                }
            }
            return false;
        } 
    };

    viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(x);
}
```

Here I now save the listener to a variable `x`.

onDestroy method:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(x != null){
        topContent.getViewTreeObserver()
            .removeOnPreDrawListener(x);
    }
}
```

I then check to see if the variable `x` is null, if it is remove the listener?

Am I correct in this? Thanks

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. Do you have a image set as a background any where? You  need to scale down the image

Comment: post some code, you have a leak somewhere

Comment: So I've added the code from the activity it crashed on. I do have a background image that I have placed in an `ImageView`

Comment: I've just noticed in my `getMargins()` method has `topContent.getViewTreeObserver()
                            .removeOnPreDrawListener(this);` twice, could it be something to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a classic memory leak situation.

Most likely, you're keeping a live reference to some UI component (or maybe even the `Activity`) in a listener or an `AsyncTask` which causes the `Activity` instance to be leaked (*kept from being garbage collected*) when you turn the device -- because due to orientation change another `Activity` instance is created and the old one is supposed to be destroyed and collected.

After you turn the device 3 times you have 4 copies of everything -- hence the OOM.

Another possibility is that you're decoding a `Bitmap` manually and not calling `recycle()` on it when your `Activity` is destroyed.

And yep, as the guys suggest in the comments, nothing more specific can be said until you post your code.

**UPD** Oh, yeah, now that the code is there, most likely the source of your problem is somewhere in the anonymous classes (the `OnPreDrawListener` and the `Runnable`). First, not all conditions guarantee that your listener gets removed -- I'm not sure this is exactly what's causing the leak but consider checking if the listener is still around and removing it in `onDestroy()` also. But the more general idea is that any untrivial anonymous and nested non-static classes are a bad idea because they store an implicit reference to the instance of the containing class -- in this case, the `Activity`. Should anything unsuspected happen with any of that code -- it can cause the containing instance to be retained.

So, safest strategy is to avoid using non-static nested (let alone anonymous) classes  unless the logic they carry is so trivial that you're absolutely sure about the implications.

My go-to approach is to create static nested `Listener`s (or `AsyncTask`s, `Runnable`s, etc.) that refer to everything they need via `WeakReference`. Most obvious solution is to store the reference to the `Activity` in a member `WeakReference<InstructionsActivity>` and check it for `null` when the corresponding code gets executed. If it returns `null` - that means your `Activity` got destroyed, just `return` immediately.

**UPD**
Also, consider using Eclipse MAT ([here's a good article](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html), google around for more) to detect memory leaks. It has an awesome ability to run OQL queries on an HPROF dump file, this way you can query for your suspect leaked class (the activity class) and if there are two or more of them -- you know you have a problem. It will even show you what objects keep them retained -- look for *paths to GC root*

Comment: I've just added some code from the activity that crashed do you need anything else?

Comment: Hi thanks for the update, this seems like the only logical thing it could be I've been trying to reproduce the error but can't seem to do it, How would I check if the `OnPreDrawListener()` method is null? I'm saving it to a variable now

Comment: Do I just check to see if the variable is null and use the `topContent.getViewTreeObserver()
         .removeOnPreDrawListener(variable);` method and remove it there?

Comment: Sorry don't have much time now. Just store the OnPreDrawListener as a member variable of your activity. When unregistering, set it to `null`. in `onDestroy()` check it for null and if it's not -- unregister and set to `null`

Comment: no problem, Thanks for your help mate I have updated the question with my new code, if you get time see what you think. Thanks again

Comment: But also, when you remove it in the listener code, null it. So that you don't remove it 2 times: when you get to `onDestroy()` if it's already been removed, you don't have to do that again.

Comment: Also, the whole margin measurement thing looks kind of overcomplicated, what are you trying to achieve there, maybe there's a better approach.

Comment: I needed to get the height of the web views once they had been rendered to add margin to the top of the view because with there being so many different screen sizes, I couldn't just hard code the margin in, how would you do it differently?

Comment: You can have different hardcoded margins for different screen densities. Margin usually isn't something that requires absolute precision, but should rather be consistent with visual rhytm of the UI around it, and Android has both mechanisms and UI guidelines for that. You should start here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: you see it does in this application because there is a background image that has to be still, then there is a scrollview above the background, the reason I have to set it the way I have is because I need a button to be at the very botton of the screen, setting the margin in different folders for different screens would result in the button not being in the correct place

Comment: hm. I'm not sure I'm getting that. But anyway, if this works for you, it's probably ok. If it's not, then it should be a separate question :)

Comment: If I explained it better you would understand why I've done it this way lol. anyways got everythign working like a charm so it's statying the way it is. lol Thanks for your help dude

Answer (score 0):

This may be causes of configuration change add below property in your mainifest file inside the activity.you can change as per your requirement

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|screenLayout"
```

Comment: I want it to redraw the layout because I have a different layout for landscape then I do portrait. I could however use the `onCOnfigurationChange` method to redraw the the correct layouts?